# Currency rate calculator to solve the '403 forbidden' from Yahoo

Tags: r

As many of us, I had a huge problem when Yahoo decided unilaterally to stop providing their Yahoo Finance API, and got the famous '403 forbidden' message. "It has come to our attention that this service is being used in violation of the Yahoo Terms of Service. As such, the service is being discontinued. For all future markets and equities data research, please refer to finance.yahoo.com."

In my case, all my main script was based on their currency data which I couldn´t obtain anymore. I was using the function "getQuote" from the package "quantmod" to obtain the data from Yahoo.

For all those looking for equities, you can still get the information from "getSymbol.google" function from "quantmod". But sadly for me, the function did not work for currencies (or, I hadn´t been able to figure it out).

As a shortcut, I have created a a function to obtain the data from google finance calculator (https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=EUR&to=USD&meta=ei%3DEiYAWtCXJ5fBU7HYsig).

As you can see as follows (I have call it CcyCalculator as a lack of other ideas) I have created a function were you can specify quantity, from which currency and to what currency you want the currency rate.

```
CcyCalculator <- function(qty=1, convto="USD", QuoteCcy){
url <- paste("http://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=", qty, "&from=", QuoteCcy, "&to=", convto, "&meta=ei%3DNR4AWtmFOojPUfiBisAE", sep = "") ## look for the web calculator and print it
x <- read.csv(file=url)
x <- x[364,1] ## look for the value
x <-  gsub("^.*?bld>", "", x) ## clean value
x <-  gsub( " .*$", "", x ) ## more cleaning
x <- print(t(as.matrix(c(QuoteCcy, x)))) ## print the value in a matrix 
}
```

Later, as I need many currencies values and all in USD conversion rate, I have created a loop to get all the values for a vector.

You need to specify your vector with the currencies you want to obtain.

```
CcyVector <- c("EUR", "GBP", "JPY", "CHF")
```

Then you need to create an empty data frame to fill with the data.

```
CcyF <- data.frame(x= integer(0), y= numeric(0))
```

Finally, we loop our CcyVector with our CcyCalculator

```
for (i in CcyVector){
Ccy <- paste(CcyCalculator(QuoteCcy = i)) ## loop through CcyVector
CcyF <- as.data.frame(rbind(CcyF, Ccy)) ## ad all the values into our empty data frame
colnames(CcyF) <- c("CCY", "to_USD")
}
```

And, as you can see, we end up with a data frame with currencies values in USD

CCY      to_USD

EUR      1.1588

GBP      1.3152

JPY      0.0088

CHF      1.0030

I don´t know if this will help anyone, but I´ve been trying to look for it for a couple of days and I couldn´t find anything like it.

If anybody has a better way to solve my problem, or can rewrite my function in a more clear and clean way that would be appreciated (ie, the loop could be substituted with lapply as [lapply(CcyVector, CcyCalculator(x))] but I couldn´t make it work)

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a useful technique that I have used to replace yahoo stock prices in an Excel spreadsheet https://office-watch.com/2016/excel-stock-prices-from-google-finance/.  The trick of using a continuously updated Google Sheets spreadsheet may well work for currencies as well, and it is just as easily imported into R as into Excel.

Comment: I realize finserv types likely always have Excel running, but it's an unnecessary dependency that is often fraught with peril.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect folks will likely close your question (as it's more of a blog post than something for SO). However, there some things below which may likely be useful to others who stumble upon this Q&A:

```
#' Convert currencies using Google Finance calculator
#'
#' @note from, to and qty lengths must meet the following conditions
#'
#' - from, to and qty must all be length 1, *OR*
#' - from, to and qty must all be the _same_ length, *OR*
#' - from can be any length, to can be length 1 and qty can be length 1 or the length of from
#'
#' @param from,to character vectors of currencies to convert from and to.
#' @param qty numeric vector of "from" quantities to convert to "to"
currency_converter <- function(from, to = "USD", qty = 1) {

  # require() only has "real" overhead the first time but we need to
  # ensure these dependencies are loaded and this isn't in a package

  require(httr, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
  require(xml2, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
  require(rvest, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
  require(purrr, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
  require(dplyr, quietly=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

  # Local environment variables we'll use liberally in the nested function

  meta <- valid_froms <- valid_tos <- NULL

  # Performs a single conversion

  .currency_converter <- function(.from, .to, .qty) {

    Sys.sleep(5) # just b/c *you* want something for free doesn't give you the right to abuse resources

    if (is.na(.qty)) return(NULL)

    # Prime "meta" & validators with an initial call to the calculator
    # we'll keep updating "meta" in the calculator call until all
    # conversions are done

    if (is.null(meta)) {

      prime <- GET("https://finance.google.com/finance/converter")
      stop_for_status(prime) # shld only happen if you abuse the API or lose network
      prime <- content(prime, as="parsed")

      meta <<- html_attr(html_node(prime, "input[name='meta']"), "value")

      # Get valid from/to & store for later use

      valid_froms <<- html_attr(html_nodes(prime, "select[name='from'] > option"), "value")
      valid_tos <<- html_attr(html_nodes(prime, "select[name='to'] > option"), "value")

    }

    # Make sure the currencies are valid but don't abort if not, just
    # return a data frame with NA for the converted value

    if (!(.from %in% valid_froms)) return(data_frame(from = .from, from_qty = .qty, to = .to, to_qty = NA_real_))
    if (!(.to %in% valid_tos)) return(data_frame(from = .from, from_qty = .qty, to = .to, to_qty = NA_real_))

    # Now make the API call

    httr::GET(
      url = "https://finance.google.com/finance/converter",
      query = list(a = .qty, from = .from, to = .to, meta = meta)
    ) -> res

    stop_for_status(res) # shld only happen if you abuse the API or lose network

    res <- content(res, as="parsed")
    res <- html_text(html_node(res, "div#currency_converter_result > span"))
    res <- as.numeric(sub(" .*$", "", res))

    data_frame(from = .from, from_qty = .qty, to = .to, to_qty = res)

  }

  # Ensure valid params

  if (length(from) > 1) {

    if (length(to) > 1) {
      if (length(to) != length(from)) {
        stop("`from` and `to` must either be the same length or `to` must be a single currency", call.=FALSE)
      }
    } else {
      to <- rep(to, length(from))
    }

    if (length(qty) > 1) {
      if (length(qty) != length(from)) {
        stop("`from`, `to` and `qty` must either be the same length or `qty` must be a single currency", call.=FALSE)
      }
    } else {
      qty <- rep(qty, length(from))
    }

  }

  pmap_dfr(
    data_frame(
      .from = trimws(toupper(from)),
      .to = trimws(toupper(to)),
      .qty = as.numeric(qty)
    ),
    .currency_converter
  )

}
```

Let's see if it works:

```
currency_converter("SOS")
## # A tibble: 1 x 4
##    from from_qty    to to_qty
##   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
## 1   SOS        1   USD 0.0017

currency_converter(c("EUR", "GBP", "JPY", "CHF"))
## # A tibble: 4 x 4
##    from from_qty    to to_qty
##   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
## 1   EUR        1   USD 1.1570
## 2   GBP        1   USD 1.3138
## 3   JPY        1   USD 0.0087
## 4   CHF        1   USD 0.9992

currency_converter(
  c("EUR", "GBP", "JPY", "CHF"),
  rev(c("EUR", "GBP", "JPY", "CHF"))
)
## # A tibble: 4 x 4
##    from from_qty    to   to_qty
##   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
## 1   EUR        1   CHF   1.1580
## 2   GBP        1   JPY 150.2182
## 3   JPY        1   GBP   0.0067
## 4   CHF        1   EUR   0.8634

set.seed(8675309)
currency_converter(c("EUR", "GBP", "JPY", "CHF"), "ZAR", sample(20, 4))
## # A tibble: 4 x 4
##    from from_qty    to   to_qty
##   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
## 1   EUR        4   ZAR  65.6464
## 2   GBP       10   ZAR 186.5290
## 3   JPY       14   ZAR   1.7388
## 4   CHF       18   ZAR 255.2202

currency_converter(
  c("EUR", "GBP", "JPY", "ZZZ"),
  rev(c("EUR", "ZZZ", "JPY", "CHF")),
  sample(20, 4)
)
## # A tibble: 4 x 4
##    from from_qty    to   to_qty
##   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
## 1   EUR        6   CHF    6.948
## 2   GBP       13   JPY 1952.600
## 3   JPY       18   ZZZ       NA
## 4   ZZZ       15   EUR       NA
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It´s really helpful. I´m new around here, I did not know about the blog type of questions, i´ll have that in mind next time!